# Can google-maps be embedded without widgets?

Tags: google-maps

When embedding google maps on a web-page with an iFrame, is there a way that it can show without widgets?

currently it is showing the zoom-in/ zoom-out button, a large popup in the top-left corner showing the address of the marker, the satellite preview image in the bottom left,and the terms of use bar...

i feel this is a bit too much. is there a way this can be customised?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the default-ui in google-map.

For that you need to add this part of code in init function.

```
function initMap() {
        ..
          disableDefaultUI: true
        });
      }
```

For detail look at [How to disable default ui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI)

Comment: so this is not possible without using the API?

Comment: You should just create a java-script function and call it on onload. After disabling the default UI you can have  fine control over panControl , zoomControl: and other buttons.